# KIE Java Client Exception - Server that this client is connected to has no capabilities to handle ProcessServicesClient

Tags: jbpm, bpmn, kie

I am trying to start a JBPM process (a simple hello world process) using the KIE Java Client from the example in the following link:
[Redhat Decision Manager documentation Section 2](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_process_automation_manager/7.1/html-single/interacting_with_red_hat_process_automation_manager_using_kie_apis/index#kie-server-java-api-requests-proc_kie-apis)

at a high level here's whats happening
Create configuration
`config = KieServicesFactory.newRestConfiguration(url, user, pass);`
Create a serviceClient
`kieServicesClient = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(conf);`
Create processClient  `processServicesClient = kieServicesClient.getServicesClient(ProcessServicesClient.class);`

At this last point the client quits with the following exception

```
org.kie.server.api.exception.KieServicesException: Server that this client is connected to has no capabilities to handle ProcessServicesClient
    at org.kie.server.client.impl.KieServicesClientImpl.getServicesClient(KieServicesClientImpl.java:158)
    at com.hcentive.rule.kie.client.DroolsDMNClient.initialize(DroolsDMNClient.java:74)
    at com.hcentive.rule.kie.client.DroolsDMNClient.<init>(DroolsDMNClient.java:44)
```

It doesn't seem like there is much on this topic when I googled it. Someone here seemed to have [this issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-usage/RCa21Gca0Ts) and the solution was to make the KIE server and the client version to be in sync. My server and the client versions are the same 7.39.0-Final.

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that you have installed RHDM (Red Hat Decision Manager). This product is enterprise version of Drools engine - it's a product focused on rules only. There are no process capabilities included in this product and that's why you are seeing this error. You need to install RHPAM (Red Hat Process Automation Manager) if you want to start working with processes.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. The suggestions that I got was to match the versions like you so tried 7.39.0.Final.

I also tried 7.8.0.Final because I have rhpam-installed(Red Hat Process Automation Manager) on version 7.8.0.

I saw that some suggest that you check your Execution server tab to make sure the server configuration you have does have the process selected under capabilities. This is the checkboxes you should be able to see them.

I tried looking at the user I used and gave him owner rights under the Contributors tab under your project.

Not sure if any of this helps you but glad you asked the question because this did not solve my problem.